# Tried referencing a Custom setting Text area(255) field inside a Formula in salesforce flow, but somehow it is erroring out saying field not exists

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, custom-field, customsetting, record-access-level

Referencing Text area field belonging to custom Settings heirarchy object inside a condition formula of a Record Triggered Flow is giving following Error: Field **$Setup.CustomSettingName__c[image].test__c does not exist. Check spelling.**

Answer (score 2):

Text Area fields are not supported in Formulas. You can vote for the [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjTTUAZ/text-area-long-formula-support) for now.